# While Downloading Invoice in pdf facing 404 error

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

i am using laravel cashier 10 and stripe 7. I am trying to download invoice pdf but facing error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWj11.png)

code for downloading pdf

```
 return $request->user()->downloadInvoice($invoiceId, [
        'vendor'  => 'Focous Chain',
        'product' => Plan::GetPlanById(Auth::user()->subscription('default')->stripe_plan)['interval'],
    ]);
```

and route is

```
    Route::get('download/invoices/{invoice}', 'AccountController@downloadInvoice')->name('download.invoice');
```

and in view

```
<a href="{{route('download.invoice', ['id',$invoice->id])}}" class="btn btn-primary">download</a>
```

Comment: Can you try: `<a href="{{ route('download.invoice', $invoice) }}" class="btn btn-primary">download</a>`

Comment: Facing this issue
Object of class Laravel\Cashier\Invoice could not be converted to string (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\focuschain\resources\views\dashboard\plan.blade.php)

Comment: And `<a href="{{ route('download.invoice', $invoice->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">download</a>` ?

Comment: thanks alot Remul its work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are generating the route in the wrong way:

```
<a href="{{route('download.invoice', ['id',$invoice->id])}}" class="btn btn-primary">download</a>
```

will generate:

```
focuschain.com/download/invoices/id?in_1HDOhdEft5GkDC4vVsV36cpy
```

Here you are passing `id` as the route parameter `{invoice}` which obviously is not correct, it should be `in_1HDOhdEft5GkDC4vVsV36cpy`

```
focuschain.com/download/invoices/in_1HDOhdEft5GkDC4vVsV36cpy
```

In order to achieve this you can do the following:

```
<a href="{{ route('download.invoice', $invoice->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a value with the wrong argument in your view for the download route.

You have to pass as:

`<a href="{{ route('download.invoice', ['invoice', $invoice->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">download</a>`

Comment: still facing same issue

Comment: Can you check the url if id is being added to the url or not